# Using the nextSiblingElement tag to make my list items go down the page when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want my list items to go down the page when I click on the down button, but they are not firing and the console is not giving me any error's as to what's wrong. All of my other buttons work perfectly 
as well as everything else is working the way it should. I examined the way my code and cannot see why my nextElementSibling code is not working as it should.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript and the DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="myHeading">JavaScript and the DOM</h1>
    <p>Making a web page interactive</p>
    <button id="toggleList">Hide list</button>
    <div class="list">
      <p class="description">Things that are purple:</p>
      <input type="text" class="description">
      <button class="description">Change list description</button>
      <ul>
        <li>grapes
          <button class="up">Up</button>
          <button class="down">Down</button>
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>

        </li>
        <li>amethyst
          <button class="up">Up</button>
          <button class="down">Down</button>
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </li>
        <li>lavender
          <button class="up">Up</button>
          <button class="down">Down</button>
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </li>
        <li>plums
          <button class="up">Up</button>
          <button class="down">Down</button>
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" class="addItemInput">
      <button class="addItemButton">Add item</button>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const toggleList = document.getElementById('toggleList');
const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list');
const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('input.description');
const descriptionP = document.querySelector('p.description');
const descriptionButton = document.querySelector('button.description');
const listUl = listDiv.querySelector('ul');
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('input.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('button.addItemButton');

listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    if (event.target.className == 'remove') {
    let li = event.target.parentNode;
    let ul = li.parentNode;
    ul.removeChild(li);
    }
    if (event.target.className == 'up') {
      let li = event.target.parentNode;
      let prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
      let ul = li.parentNode;
      if (prevLi) {
      ul.insertBefore(li, prevLi);
      }
    if (event.target.className == 'down') {
      let li = event.target.parentNode;
      let nextLi = li.nextElementSibling;
      let ul = li.parentNode;
      if (nextLi) {
      ul.insertBefore(nextLi, li);
      }
    }
   }
  }
});


toggleList.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (listDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    toggleList.textContent = 'Hide list';
    listDiv.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    toggleList.textContent = 'Show list';                        
    listDiv.style.display = 'none';
  }                         
});

descriptionButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  descriptionP.innerHTML = descriptionInput.value + ':';
  descriptionInput.value = '';
});

addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  addItemInput.value = '';
});
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me, not seeing issues, but obviously there is one.  Seems to me you could simplify your code quite a bit by using `insertAdjacentElement()` though - and then not having to deal with the parent at all.  Would make your code simpler and thus easier to debug.  This type of DOM manipulation is never fun, but not having to refer to parent nodes all the time can make things less frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF statement for the 'down' class is nested within the IF statement for the 'up' class. If you relocate it after the 'up' section it will work

https://jsfiddle.net/msiz2920/ymoktpf1/

```
console.log(" A ");
const toggleList = document.getElementById('toggleList');
const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list');
const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('input.description');
const descriptionP = document.querySelector('p.description');
const descriptionButton = document.querySelector('button.description');
const listUl = listDiv.querySelector('ul');
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('input.addItemInput');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('button.addItemButton');
console.log(" B ");
listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
console.log(" C ");
  if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
     console.log(" D ");

    if (event.target.className == 'remove') {
            console.log(" C.1 ");
        let li = event.target.parentNode;
        let ul = li.parentNode;
        ul.removeChild(li);
    }

    if (event.target.className == 'up') {
            console.log(" C.2 ");
        let li = event.target.parentNode;
        let prevLi = li.previousElementSibling;
        let ul = li.parentNode;
        if (prevLi) {  
            console.log(" C.3 ");
            ul.insertBefore(li, prevLi);
        }

    }

    if (event.target.className == 'down') {
                console.log(" C.4 ");
            let li = event.target.parentNode;
            let nextLi = li.nextElementSibling;
            let ul = li.parentNode;
            if (nextLi) {
                ul.insertBefore(nextLi, li);
                    }
            }

    }


  console.log(" E ");
});


toggleList.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (listDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    toggleList.textContent = 'Hide list';
    listDiv.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    toggleList.textContent = 'Show list';                        
    listDiv.style.display = 'none';
  }                         
});

descriptionButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  descriptionP.innerHTML = descriptionInput.value + ':';
  descriptionInput.value = '';
});

addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = addItemInput.value;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  addItemInput.value = '';
});
```